# On Spring Boot, how to get the html to communicate with the model

Tags: html, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

This probably a very simple question, but I can't figure it out alone. I have the following controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestController extends AbstractCloudController {

    private final EquipmentRepository equipmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    TestController(EquipmentRepository er) {
        equipmentRepository = er;   
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET) void index() {
        List<String> codes = equipmentRepository.findAllEquipments();
        String output = "";
        for (String code : codes) {
            output += "ID "+code+"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And the following index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="./bower_components/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div class="outer">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-controller="TestController" ng-cloak="ng-cloak">
                <p>This is a test page</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/hello.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the information from the controller to the server side without it overriding the html? When I make the controller return something, it ends up overwriting the html and printing only the equipment code instead instead of the "Hello World", even the page title doesn't show.

Comment: First, if you are going to use Views you need to use `@Controller` no `@RestController`, the method have to return a view or modelview and finally you need to modify your view and put the code for use the information. In this link you can see more info: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: What does your hello.js look like for your Angular controller configuration?  My guess is that because you did not specify a path in @RequestMapping then you are returning the response from the Spring controller rather than the index.html page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you returned in your controller, but you may check this document: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types

If you want to print the content of **output**, you may add it to a **Model**

```java
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, Model model) void index() {
    List<String> codes = equipmentRepository.findAllEquipments();
    String output = "";
    for (String code : codes) {
        output += "ID "+code+"\n";
    }
    model.addAttribute("output", output);
```

}

then use JSP Expression Language to get the content

```jsp
${output}
```

PS. Spring will treat a returned string as view name, not html content by default.

Comment: I tried this but I started getting a "circular view path" error, so I added the `@ResponseBody` tag which got around this problem, but it started overwriting the index again, so my output an empty page...

Comment: Like @sergio-garcia-alonso says, since you use @RestController but @Controller, it's implicity @ResponseBody on method level according to @ RestController documentation, which means Spring will try to convert anything you returned to string and write to response. You might just return a string ```@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET) String index() {```

Comment: I suggest you use developer tools to see what actually browser received including response body and headers(mostly F12), some browsers will display an empty page but it did receive something under header **Content-Type: application/json;**